# Combinatorics - Why is this approach wrong?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Assume we have 10 couples (couple = male and female in this question)

How many ways there are to create a group of 6 people out of them that will have at least 1 male and 1 female but NO COUPLES AT ALL?

My first approach was to choose 1 peson from the total 20, then choose 1 person out of the 9 remaining couples (so i get the opossite sex) then choose 4 couples and take one person out of each.

Why is that approach wrong?

THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: You are over counting.  There's no way to tell which of your group is the "special" one you chose first.

Comment: I'd say it was easier to just choose the $6$ couples who will be represented and then choose one person from each, finally subtracting off the all male and the all female selections.

Comment: It would be useful if you write which numbers does your procedure produce.

Comment: @lulu it is exactly what I did after I saw my first approach didnt work out. I am wondering what is the logical mistake in the first approach. could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Suppose the group is $\{m_1,f_2, m_3, f_4, m_5,f_6\}$.  using your method, I could get that group by choosing $m_1,f_2$ first and then the rest, or I could get it by choosing $m_3,f_6$ first, and so on. You are counting this particular group lots and lots of times.

Comment: but can I assure that the second pick will be opposite sex in that method? I think I can't...

Comment: What do you mean?  I used your method.  I first built that group by selecting $m_1$ as the special male, and then selecting $f_2$ as the special female. Then I chose the other groups $3,4,5,6$ and picked one person from each.  But I could have started with $m_3$ and $f_6$ just as easily and built the same group.

Comment: It's difficult to see how to even correct your method.  My example gets counted $9$ times (as there are $3$ ways to choose the special male and $3$ ways to choose the special female).  If the group has $M$ males and $F$ females then you are counting in $M\times F$ times.

Comment: Sorry, I have to run off.  Study my comments.  Your method is wrong even for three couples...write it out explicitly in that case.

Comment: @lulu Your "Suppose the group" comment looks like a complete answer to me -- why not post it?

Comment: If you could look at all the combinatorics questions on this site, you would find many that the asker originally approached in a similar way: choose enough people/balls/socks/whatever so that you satisfy the "you must have one of each of these" criteria, then fill up the set without violating any of the other criteria. It's intuitively appealing and almost always gives a wrong answer, usually by overcounting. Once you have a better intuition it's usually not hard to spot where the overcounting occurs.

Answer (score 1):

An approach which works:

- How many ways of choosing $6$ couples from the $10$ available?
- How many ways of choosing an individual from each of these $6$ couples?
- How many ways of choosing $6$ individuals so none come from the same couple?
- How many ways of choosing $6$ individuals so none come from the same couple and none are male?
- How many ways of choosing $6$ individuals so none come from the same couple and none are female?
- How many ways of choosing $6$ individuals so none come from the same couple and at least one is male and at least one is female?

This will give $13020$ possible choices

Your approach of $20\times 9 \times 16 \times 14 \times 12 \times 10 = 4838400$ is too big because it takes account of order.  If you divide by $6!$ you get $6720$ which is too small because you force a particular gender on one selection, when there are other possibilities as to the gender distribution.

Answer (score 0):

- Choose $6$ couples to start with: $\binom{10}6$
- Choose one member from each couple $2^6$
- Exclude all male/all female combos $2\cdot\binom{10}6$

Putting it all together, $\binom{10}6\cdot(2^6 - 2) = 13020$